# Comparing List to String in neo4j, reading from HTML

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Here's my problem:
Let's suppose that I have an HTML file containing a table like the one below

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> keyword1 </td>
        <td>
            <p> paragraph 1 </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> keyword2 </td>
        <td>
            <p> paragraph 2 </p>
            <p> paragraph 3 </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> keyword3 </td>
        <td>
            <p> paragraph 1 </p>
            <p> paragraph 3 </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I use the following code to extract the infos from the HTML

```
CALL apoc.load.html("file:///input_HTML.html",{kwords:"table tr td:eq(1)",
paragraphs:"table tr td:eq(2)",paragraphsList:"table tr td:eq(2) p"}) YIELD value
```

What I would like to have at the end, would be, for each input line of the table something similar to the statement below, but of course created dynamically upon reading the HTML file

```
CREATE(:kwords {name:"keyword1"})-[:'APPEARS_IN']->(:paragraph {name:"paragraph1"})
```

The tricky part is to get the paragraphs name ... any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be going after `td` element with an index of `1`; the element index starts at `0`.

```
...
paragraphs:"table tr td:eq(1)",paragraphsList:"table tr td:eq(1)
...
```

But I am not sure that still enables you to do what you want.

How about getting the keywords in one pass and then selecting the paragraphs for each keyword in a second pass.

```
CALL apoc.load.html("file:///input_HTML.html",{kwords: "tr td:eq(0)"}) YIELD value
UNWIND value.kwords AS kw
WITH kw.text AS kw
CALL apoc.load.html("file:///input_HTML.html",{paras: 'tr:contains(' + kw + ') td:eq(1) p'}) YIELD value
UNWIND value.paras AS para
MERGE (k:kwords {name: kw }) 
MERGE (p:paragraph {name: para.text}) 
MERGE (k)-[:APPEARS_IN]->(p)
RETURN *
```

Comment: Excellent. Your solution not based on substring is perfect!

Comment: Dave: what if I need to add a filter to remove empty paragraphs ?

Comment: hey sorry, busy day, so you select a paragraph but there is no text like `<p></p>`? And para.text is an emptry string?

Comment: No Worry Dave and thanks for ansering: 
Exactly ...let's say that the table is like the following:
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> keyword1 </td>
        <td>
            <p> paragraph 1 </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> keyword2 </td>
        <td>
            <p> paragraph 2 </p>
            <p> paragraph 3 </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> keyword3 </td>
        <td>
            <p> paragraph 1 </p>
            <p> paragraph 3 </p>
<p> </p>
        </td>
      
    </tr>
</table>
And that I want to ignore it ...

Comment: I created another quesiton, as I have issue on WITH scope and nested CALL to apoc.load.html 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59863758/neo4j-call-apoc-load-html-with-headers