# neo4j : CALL APOC.LOAD.HTML with HEADERs

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have the following table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> header 1</th>
        <th> header 2</th>
        <th> header 3</th>
    <tr>
        <td> keyword1 </td>
        <td> value1.2 </td>
        <td>
            <p> paragraph 1 </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> keyword2 </td>
        <td> value2.2 </td>
        <td>
            <p> paragraph 2 </p>
            <p> paragraph 3 </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> keyword3 </td>
        <td> value3.2</td>
        <td>
            <p> paragraph 1 </p>
            <p> paragraph 3 </p>
            <p> </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What method you suggest to use to load it via apoc.load.html 
and apoc.node.create or apoc.node.merge
so that headers are used dynamically as node properties names?

It should create dynamic equivalent to the below static code:

```
MERGE(:node {name:keyword1, header2:value1.2})-[:R]->(:header3 {name:paragrap1})

MERGE(:node {name:keyword2, header2:value2.2})-[:R]->(:header3 {name:paragrap2})
MERGE(:node {name:keyword2, header2:value2.2})-[:R]->(:header3 {name:paragrap3})

MERGE(:node {name:keyword3, header2:value3.2})-[:R]->(:header3 {name:paragrap1})
MERGE(:node {name:keyword3, header2:value3.2})-[:R]->(:header3 {name:paragrap3})
```

I wrote the code below ...

```
// 999. SAMPLE CODE
CALL apoc.load.html("file:///C:/Users/sesa407003/Desktop/CURRENT%20PROJECTS/NEO4J/doc_start.html",{line: "table tr"}) yield value as lineList

CALL apoc.load.html("file:///doc_start.html",{header: "table tr th"}) yield value as headersList

UNWIND range(1, length(lineList.line) -1) as j
//with j,i,source
CALL apoc.load.html("file:///doc_start.html",{value: "table tr:eq("+j+") td"}) yield value as valueList
CALL apoc.merge.node(["node"], {name:valueList.value[2].text}) yield node as source
UNWIND range(0,length(headersList.header)-2) as i
CALL apoc.create.setProperties(source,[headersList.header[i].text],[valueList.value[i].text]) yield node
CALL apoc.load.html("file:///doc_start.html",{paragraphs: "table tr:eq("+j+") td:eq(2) p"}) yield value as paragraphsList
UNWIND paragraphsList.paragraphs as paragraph
MERGE(target:dashboard {name:paragraph.text})
MERGE(source)-[:R]->(target)
return *
```

It seems to work ... but when I try to remove empty paragraphs, like the last on keyword3 ... I don't find the right syntax for WHERE or CASE WHEN or apoc.case.when

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your cypher and made a few changes. I expect it gets you closer to your end state.

To remove the empty paragraph I added this little `WITH` block

```
WITH source, paragraph.text AS para
WHERE trim(para) <> ""
```

I also changed a few of the array indexes to get the right data from the table.

```
CALL apoc.load.html("file:///table.html",{line: "table tr"}) yield value as lineList
CALL apoc.load.html("file:///table.html",{header: "table tr th"}) yield value as headersList
UNWIND range(1, size(lineList.line) - 1) as j
CALL apoc.load.html("file:///table.html",{value: "table tr:eq("+j+") td"}) yield value as valueList
CALL apoc.merge.node(["node"], {name:valueList.value[0].text}) yield node as source
UNWIND range(0,size(headersList.header)-2) as i
CALL apoc.create.setProperties(source,[headersList.header[i].text],[valueList.value[i].text]) yield node
CALL apoc.load.html("file:///table.html",{paragraphs: "table tr:eq("+j+") td:eq(2) p"}) yield value as paragraphsList
UNWIND paragraphsList.paragraphs as paragraph
WITH source, paragraph.text AS para
WHERE trim(para) <> ""
MERGE(target:dashboard {name:para})
MERGE(source)-[:R]->(target)
RETURN *
```

Comment: Thank You very much Dave.
Still not familiar with the code ...